# Which column failed in C# and MySQL? Can't see it in the Exception object

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime, mysql-connector

I am in .NET C# using MySQL database. Sometimes, MySQL throws an error, for example:

```
Datetime function: datetime field overflow
```

If I inspect the Exception object, I havent been able to find any information on *which column failed* (please note that I am not asking why the error occurs, but how I can get info on what COLUMN that fails)

[image]

Am I blind, or isn't it there? If not, it's completely weird that the error doesn't say which field/column failed. If I have many DateTimes in whatever I am persisting to db, then I have to go through them all, and guess which one fails.

Any pointers here?

Comment: can you show us some code? it might be a dd/mm/yyyy vs mm/dd/yyyy thing

Comment: Hey =) I know what the MySql error is, that isnt the question. My question is if it is at all possible for C# connector/MySql to tell me what column/field that fails. (The problem with the DateTime is that it is DateTime.MaxValue, which MySql cannot handle, at least not prior 5.6.4 I think)

Comment: The error message comes from MySQL Server; if it doesn't provide any column information then the C# connector won't be able to provide any additional information. (You should get the exact same error message if you executed the same SQL in MySQL Workbench.)

Comment: Yep, exactly. I was just wondering if I missed something? Its very strange to me that MySql doesnt provide the faulty column...